# Magento 2 - What's the current way to print the ProductID in Template during Product View?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-template

I need to print the ProductID in my phtml template, and the easiest way to do this seems to be

```php
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class MyTemplate extends Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProductId()
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        if ($product) {
            return $product->getId();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

While this works, Registry class is deprecated, but I have troube to find a different way.
I tried to implement Argumentinterface to the template, like this:

```php
class MyTemplate extends Template implements ArgumentInterface
```

And then add this to my layout.xml:

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\MyTemplate" name="abc" template="MyVendor_MyModule::my_html.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="product" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

And then retrieve it like this:

```php
$this->_product = $data['product'];
```

However then I get the error:
`Instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface is expected, got Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor instead.`

All I want is to have the current product ID in a product view, how can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current product, one of the recommended ways is:

Extend or use block class: `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`.
Get product using: `$block->getCurrentProductId()` in your phtml file.

```
    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class MyTemplate extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var View
     */
     private View $view;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
         View $view,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->view = $view;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProductId()
    {
        $product = $this->view->getProduct();
        if ($product) {
            return $product->getId();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in my tests this seems to work fine!